# Sqlite3: What's the correct mojo for "delete ... where not in ...?"

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm simply trying to delete all of the rows in one table which don't have a corresponding row in another table. Something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.pk NOT IN (SELECT fk FROM table2);
```

But I must be doing something stupid.  A `SELECT` query – to find the rows that I want to delete – seems easy enough *(and produces the right answers),* but I'm just not getting anywhere with `DELETE`.  Either it doesn't run at all or it deletes the wrong things.

*(The queries that I have in mind work just fine on other DBMSes, but I know that SQLite's support is more limited.  And, yeah, I'm really familiar with how SQL works ... not my first rodeo.)*

Some folks have suggested something to do with `NOT EXISTS`, but I sure wish that the kind folks here would just reply with "a query that works."  My forehead will thank you ...

Comment: Are you sure that these pks in the rows that you try to delete are not referenced in another table?

Answer (score 1):

Well the only case that this code:

```
DELETE FROM wagtailcore_pagerevision 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT live_revision_id FROM wagtailcore_page);
```

would not work is if there are `null` values in the column `live_revision_id` in the table `wagtailcore_page`.
Because if there are null values then they are included in the result of the subquery:

```
SELECT live_revision_id FROM wagtailcore_page
```

so for every `id` of `wagtailcore_pagerevision` not existing in the results of the subquery, this:

```
IN (SELECT live_revision_id FROM wagtailcore_page)
```

returns `null` because it is compared (also) to `null`, and `NOT IN` finally returns `null`, meaning *unknown* or *undefined* which of course is not `TRUE`.
From [Comparison Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) (for MySQL but it applies to SQLite too as it is SQL standard):

> To comply with the SQL standard, IN returns NULL not only if the
>   expression on the left hand side is NULL, but also if no match is
>   found in the list and one of the expressions in the list is NULL.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QXptgQj6uE7TbYD6aKK8M/3).
So a solution to your problem would be:

```
DELETE FROM wagtailcore_pagerevision 
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT live_revision_id 
  FROM wagtailcore_page 
  WHERE live_revision_id IS NOT NULL
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QXptgQj6uE7TbYD6aKK8M/4).

Answer (score 0):

The query in your question should work, barring things like deleting a row causing a foreign key constraint violation.

Example:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> create table table1(id integer);
sqlite> insert into table1 values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
sqlite> create table table2(id2 integer);
sqlite> insert into table2 values (1),(3),(5);
sqlite> select * from table1 where id not in (select id2 from table2);
id
----------
2
4
sqlite> delete from table1 where id not in (select id2 from table2);
sqlite> select * from table1;
id
----------
1
3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI ... here's the exact SQL query that worked:

```
delete from wagtailcore_pagerevision 
  where id in (select r.id from wagtailcore_pagerevision r 
    left join wagtailcore_page p on r.id=p.live_revision_id 
    where p.live_revision_id is null);
```

As you can see, *"pretty standard `LEFT JOIN`stuff."*

*"Thanks again, StackOverflow!"* ... Not quite sure yet where my "`LEFT` brain" was parked today ... (oh well, time for a beer) ... **:-D**